# Import error when i use wptools in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i use **jupyter notebook** that in **anaconda distribution** and when i use this line of code:

```
import wptools
```

*it gives me an import error*
i use this command in **Anaconda Prompt** :

```
conda install -c conda-forge wptools
```

but a receive that error:

```
 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like wptools is not available in conda channels.

Did you try simply using pip?

```
pip install wptools
```

Comment: Thanks it works finally , but when i used pip instead conda on Anaconda Prompt